# Какой UI движок для сайта лучше всего выбрать?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, html, ui, javascript

Какой UI движок для сайта лучше всего выбрать?
Хотел jQuery UI... Но он какой-то некрасивый, что ли...

Answer (score 1):

Для JUI есть большой список тем http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
Если же нужен не только JS, то советую взять всем известный bootstrap, для которого есть бесплатные и простые темы http://bootswatch.com , куча шаблонов, а также такие решения, как http://metroui.org.ua/ , http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/ и пр.

Comment: Посмотрел - очень понравилось! Думаю копать в сторону bootstrap. Не посоветуете ещё какие-нибудь темы, шаблоны, решения на нём???